# What’s the bit.dev equivalent of forking a repo and submitting a PR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bit.dev

What’s the [bit.dev](https://bit.dev) equivalent of forking a repo and submitting a PR? I need to make a small change to https://bit.dev/mui-org/material-ui/swipeable-drawer. I can see that it is MIT licensed, and they have a code browser, but no `.git` endpoint from what I can tell.

I am an experienced developer but I haven’t used bit.dev before. I tried to find the answer in their extensive [documentation](https://docs.bit.dev), but it focuses on creating a component from scratch. It does not offer a clear way for developers who are new to bit.dev to modify an existing component. I posted in their Slack channel but nobody responded.

[image]

Comment: I could always copy the contents of `./node_modules/@bit/mui-org.material-ui.swipeable-drawer` to a new repo of my own in order to make local modifications, but it would be nice to know how to contribute back to the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you already got your answers, but..

There are 2 ways to contribute as far as I know:

1. Know where the original repo of the author is and contribute there, which would eventually go to bit in a future release
2. Checkout the components in a totally random location using bit, update and contribute back. As far as I am aware however, in order to do this, you should have permissions on the bit organization that you are targeting and not sure there is a way to do code reviews this way..

One thing to note though is that the MUI components in bit don't seem like maintained. The last updated was 2y ago, which is a really long time, considering the amount of development that the MUI team did recently, so I would just use their lib directly.